# Classpath is empty error when running zookeeper instance

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to follow the instructions on https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart to try and start a Kafka install and then send some messages from a scala client.
I am using a windows system.
I am getting this error(see screencap) when i run the zookeeper instance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason most probably is because your directory path has a space - “Development Tools”. Try running this in a path which has no spaces. I guess the space is causing some path issues in the shell script.

Also, I assume that you downloaded the binary and not the source files?

Hope it works and let us know.